# Why is Google Drive Picker API using wrong scope when updated?

Tags: drive, google-picker

In setting up the Google Picker API I initially set it up to use this scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly which listed 2 services as expected.

When updating the picker to use this scope instead: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly (which is less privileged), the picker is still listed it as having access to the previous.

How do I update this so that it uses the correct scope? It's not clear where it's being captured.

Scope docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the user account that gave permission needs to revoke this access manually via the security tab of their Google account (beneath third party services).

In my case, I was using the one Google account, so it appeared to not be updating, but it actually was. It was just that my account continued to use the permissions I had initially granted (ie that more privileged scope)